# Run cron at different interwalls during the week

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

I want to schedule a cron job on GAE to run every 10 minutes in the period 08-16 in weekdays and 10-16 in weekends. I tried to split on two jobs with the descriptions:

`every 10 minutes mon,tue,wed,thu,fri from 07:00 to 23:00`

`every 10 minutes sat, sun from 07:00 to 23:00`

But this gives a parse error. I could probably make it work by having one job for each day but that does not seem right either.

Comment: The best way to do it would be the one job per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with the app engine cron implementation. The app engine [cron format](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#The_Schedule_Format) is a bit confusing, because it is actually two formats. One format supports specifying frequencies and time ranges (i.e., `every 10 minutes from 07:00 to 23:00`), and another supports specifying only a specific time, but on varying days (i.e., `every mon,tue,wed,thu,fri 07:00`).

You *could* write out a giant cron file with each specific time you want, but that is silly. Instead, you should just use a `every 10 minutes from 08:00 to 16:00` job, and do checking on the server to make sure it's within the day and time range (for the weekends) that you require.

Comment: Thanks! Found a feature request to change this at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7546